# LDAP client against Windows 2003 server

Tags: server, ldap

I have followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication) to get my Ubuntu 13.04 to authenticate users against Active Directory on a win2003-server. After a little trial, error and corrections, I no longer have any errors in auth.log and everything SEEMS to be OK - the only problem is that `getent passwd` etc shows that no users have been imported and no home directories have been made. If I run the `ldap test-tool`, it works fine.

What on earth could I have missed ?

Comment: Gah, casted close vote with wrong reason, but 13.04 is end-of-life and therefore off-topic on this site. Please update to 13.10.